# How to search in multiple boolean value object in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

hope you doing well.

Guys I am looking for solution of mongoose problem,
I have a object field (let say: vehicleStatus) in my User collection. Which has some keys (all are boolean values). Now I want to search from User collection based on this vehicleStatus field.

This is my Schema -

```
vehicleStatus: {
    _id: false,
    twoWheeler: Boolean,
    fourWheeler: Boolean
},
```

Now I'm searching for user if they have twoWheeler, fourWheeler or both. For example, let say John doe has {twoWheeler: true, fourWheeler: false}. So what will be the best approach to search field like this (vahicleStatus) in mongoose.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I'm searching for user if they have twoWheeler, fourWheeler **or**
>   **both**.

```
User.find({
    $expr: {
        $or: [{
            $eq: ['$vehicleStatus.twoWheeler', true]
        }, {
            $eq: ['$vehicleStatus.fourWheeler', true]
        }]
    }
}).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

You can check it here [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5inznrKH2cP)

Comment: Thanks @Hlib Derbenov for help, I implemented this approach & its working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for your matching value like this:

```
const users = await User.find({
  'vehicleStatus.twoWheeler': true,
  'vehicleStatus.fourWheeler': true,
});
```

Instead of `true`, you can also put your variable.

Comment: Thanks @technophyle I will try this way.